# How do I get the screen or window coordinates of CTreeCtrl node?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to generate a context menu but I need to know where to put it, so I need the coordinates of the node currently selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CTreeCtrl::GetItemRect()`.  This will state the rectangle of the tree node.

Comment: When you have the coordiantes in window coordinates you can use ClientToScreen to convert to Screen coordiantes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'GetCursorPos' and'HitTest method in treeclick event for displaying context menu as below.

//here i am asuming that you want to display menu on mouse rightclick

void MyDialog::OnRclickTree(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{

CPoint CurPos;

GetCursorPos(&CurPos);

CPoint CurP=CurPos;

m_pwTree.ScreenToClient(&CurPos);// m_pwTree is object of CTreeCtrl class

UINT nFlags;

HTREEITEM htItem = m_pwTree.HitTest(CurPos, &nFlags);

if (htItem != NULL ) {

CMenu menu;

CMenu* pContextMenu;

menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MyMenu)//load appropriate menu

pContextMenu=menu.GetSubMenu(0);      pContextMenu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,CurP.x,CurP.y,this,0);
}

}

Comment: GetCursorPos returns the position of the mouse cursor, not the position of a TreeCtrl node.

Comment: @Eric Brown: this method should be called when user click any tree node at that time GetCursorPos give appropriate position.

Comment: And typically you want the context menu positioned below the tree node, not at the mouse cursor, for usability reasons (and accessibility reasons).

Comment: @saroj kumar: GetCursorPos in wrong. It gives the current Cursor Position ;)
GetMessagePos should be use in such a case to detrmine the Cursor Position at the Moment the message causing the Action was involved.